# How can I find the names of AD Group policies that a user/pc is using?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am having trouble locating some settings in group policy so I can make changes due to the convoluted nature of our policies. What I would like to be able to do is go to a specific PC and see what group policies are being applied, so I can focus on those policies.

My goal would be to clean up the GP's a bit, while allowing me to "walk the tree" to see what people have implemented and what is worthless.

Thanks.

EDIT: In this specific case, I am looking to find which GP maped drives are configured in. (User Configuration --> Preferences --> Windows Settings --> Drive Maps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GPRESULT` might be what you're looking for!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755461(WS.10).aspx

Comment: This tool is excellent, but its not telling me which GP mapped drives are defined in. ( Maybe I am missing a switch )

This is my command : GPRESULT /S itdept-russh /u russound\russh  /z > c:\policy.txt

Comment: Well, I can't help you too much there, although I'd also take note of any login scripts (the mapping command might be hidden in one of those if it can't be or hasn't been explicitly defined in a group policy).

Comment: Yep, it *was* burried in a logon script.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Resultant Set Of Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on the workstation (start-->run-->rsop.msc).

It'll show you what settings have been affected by policies and tell you which GPO is the source of each configured policy setting.

Not 100% on if that's going to show you exactly what you want (mapped drive info), but at least it's another option to try. :)

Hope that helps...